# Форма смены пароля не работает

Tags: python, django

Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить ошибку. Я сделал на сайте систему аутентификации и страничку с формой смены пароля.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.template import loader, RequestContext
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from userprofile.forms import UserProfileForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.conf import settings
from userprofile.forms import ChangePasswordForm

def custom_proc(request):
    return {
        'user_profile_show': True,
    }

@login_required 
def password_page(request):     
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ChangePasswordForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            request.user.set_password(form.cleaned_data.get('password1'))
        else:
            HttpResponseRedirect('http://ya.ru/')
    else:
        form = ChangePasswordForm()

    t = loader.get_template('password_page.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {
                                    'form': form,
    }, [custom_proc])   
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from userprofile.models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.conf import settings
import os

class ChangePasswordForm(forms.Form):
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    def clean(self):    
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        password1 = cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = cleaned_data.get("password2")
        with open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, "debug_local.txt"), "wb") as f:
            f.write(bytes(password1, 'UTF-8'))

        if password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords must be same")
        else:
            return cleaned_data
```

password_page.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}User profile - pass{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>pass page</h2>

    {% for field in form %}
        {{ field.error }}
    {% endfor %}

    <form action="/userprofile/" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}

        <input type="submit" value="send" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Но пароль не изменяется после отправки формы. После отправки формы просто показывается страничка, расположенная по адресу `/userprofile/`
при этом даже не выводится в файл `debug_local.txt` отладочная информация (вообще файла такого нет).

Comment: А что написано по поводу userprofile в urls.py?

Answer (score 2):

Напишите для вашей формы [тесты](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/overview/) и убедитесь, что /userprofile/ это ваша вьюха  password_page